# How can I execute a command line task for a Spring Boot application like a Rake task?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I run a task from the command line for long-running jobs like reports from Jenkins in Spring Boot? I'm looking for something similar to Ruby on Rails Rake tasks. Rake tasks execute the code from the command line in the same application context as the web server so that you can re-use code.

- I found [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch#overview) but it sounded more like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).
- I found [command line runners](https://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/04/07/spring-boot-command-line-runner) but it said that they all run before the web server starts, so I can't *not* run it or only run one task.
- I found [scheduled tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) which sounds *perfect*, but my app is load balanced with many instances so I would not want it running multiple times at once!

I have a report where the query takes more than 30s to run, and generates a CSV file I would like to mail. I want it to run automatically each week with cron or Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hacked a solution. Suggestions welcome.

```
package com.example.tasks;

@Component
public class WeeklyReport implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Arrays.asList(args).stream().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
        if (!(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-task report:weekly"))) return;
        System.out.println("weekly report");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

And running it from a 'cron' job with

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="-task report:weekly"
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.19.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments

https://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/04/07/spring-boot-command-line-runner

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem recently and I came up with these three possible solutions:

1. Designate a "housekeeper" role that can be assumed by at most one instance whose responsibility would be complete the scheduled job. But for this the housekeeper would have to send a heartbeat to the others (through the load balancer..) and if it stops then the remaining instances must elect a new one so it seems to be an interesting but way more complex approach that I might play with later.
2. Have a single-instance external service that would run scheduled tasks and will generate the weekly csv for you
3. Have a single-instance external service that only has the capacity to make scheduled api calls and that would call your original service through the load balancer. I prefer this solution as all the resources to complete the task are already present at the original service and it preserves the functionality. It is also flexible as the scheduler service can be replaced by more light weight cron job with a curl call or merged to another service in the future..etc.

Comment: 2) How would the single-instance run scheduled tasks without the other instances running scheduled tasks using the same code? 3) The report takes longer than the load balancer allows. HTTP requests are limited to 10s and the report takes about a minute. It already has a link in the admin interface to generate the report which works in development but times out in production.

Comment: 2) you would need to either refactor that part of your original service into the new one if you can, like if it's only using the database but would not need the rest of the service. Or duplicate it to the new service (that sounds awful, I wouldn't go with this)
3) Since everything remains in the original service you can just send back an Accepted message to the Scheduler service and keep handling everything else in the main service. The Scheduler doesn't need to know about a possible failure as it can be handled in the main service (notification, logging, retires..etc)

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this goal is to consider each task as a separate application. That allows you to run them in the same JAR but have different configuration:

- `Application.java`: This is the default web application
- `FooApplication.java` This is the "Foo" task application

The directory structure looks something like the following:

```
src/
  main/java/com/example/
    Application.java
    FooApplication.java
  resources/
    application.yml
    foo-application.yml
```

For a task you want to ensure the web application type is set to `none` so that an embedded web server isn't started:

**foo-application.yml**

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

To define the application:

**FooApplication.java**

```
package com.example

import com.example.runner.BootstrapContentfulRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=Application.class)})
public class FooApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(
            SpringApplication.run(FooRunner.class, args)
        ));
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void foo() {
        // Do your task here
        System.out.println("Foo task complete!");
    }

}
```

Then, in order to run the task application:

```
mvn spring-boot:run \
  -Dspring-boot.run.main-class='com.example.FooApplication' \
  -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-Dspring.config.name=foo-application'
```